# How to rename third-party table from our module in Declarative Schema in Magento 2.3.0?

Tags: magento2, attributes, declarative-schema

I wanted to rename table **`ThirdParty`** to **`NewTable`**

So I wrote the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="ThirdParty" disabled="true" />
    <table name="NewTable" onCreate="migrateDataFromAnotherTable(ThirdParty)">
        <column name="id" xsi:type="int" identity="true" />
        <column name="code" xsi:type="varchar" length="4"/>
        <column name="title" xsi:type="text"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="id" />
        </constraint>
    </table> 
</schema>
```

After `setup:upgrade` it is showing error as,

> Element 'table', attribute 'disabled': The attribute 'disabled' is not
>   allowed. Line: 4

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by following code,

```
<table name="NewTable" onCreate="migrateDataFromAnotherTable(ThirdParty)">
```

Your code is also true, just need to remove this line,

```
<table name="ThirdParty" disabled="true" />
```

**Run Command**

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: It creates "NewTable" but don't delete "Thirdparty" table. So we get 2 tables "NewTable" and "Thirdparty".

Comment: did you regenerate the db_schema_whitelist.json file by this command `php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist –module-name=Vendorname_Packagename`? so it contains the new name in addition to the old one.

Comment: Yes, I generated whitelist files, but as we can rename column by 2 ways: 1) disabled=1 (which don't work with table) 2)Replace column name with new name (which can't do directly on third party table). So, though we generatee whitelist and use onCreate, the code for "ThirdParty" table exist in ThirdParty module and thus the table exist at the end.

Comment: we're renaming the table as defined in this docs **https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html**

Comment: @ShwetaLambhate why don't you write `InstallSchema.php` or `UpgradeSchema.php` file, you can easily rename table with that.